# What am I allowed/not permitted to do with the API?

Tags: discussion, api, documentation, legal

I have a site that will offer technical help and assistance for a certain niche of computer users.  I can either host my own forums, or tie in with stack... *but* I want to be able to make money off it possibly by advertisements or a monthly fee.

Is this permitted? I want to be on the up-and-up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commercial use of the API is permitted.

If you're just displaying content on a website, you should follow [our attribution requirements](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/).  If you have questions about a more specific use case, feel free to [contact us](https://stackapps.com/contact).

Answer (score 1):

As long as the content is properly attributed you are free to use it as you like.

as per Robert, a visible, not necessarily prominent, attribution of the content source, e.g. the site, and the poster. I believe this includes hyperlinks to both.