# Is it allowed to sell an app or get revenue with the use of the API?

Tags: support, api, legal

I've been reviewing the [terms of use](http://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) of the API, but I prefer to ask my question straight here in order to be 100% sure.

Is it allowed to create an app that:

- is paid, which revenue goes to the developer of said app,
- allows users of said app to donate money to the developer of said app,
- contains ads which revenue goes to the developer of said app,

or any combination of these?

Second question: does it matter if the app is open or close sourced?

Of course, all this assuming that the app complies with the terms of use, regarding the API attribution, the Stack Exchange trademark and brand guidelines, and the termination of the API.

**Update**: found [possible](https://stackapps.com/questions/1489/what-am-i-allowed-not-permitted-to-do-with-the-api?rq=1) [originals](https://stackapps.com/questions/2507/do-i-need-permission-to-use-the-se-api-for-a-commercial-app) that my question duplicates. My first searches didn't yield any result, I guess I should have insisted.

*If anyone has more information to provide, feel free! But I think that the links to the questions and the resources that are linked in their answers cover pretty much everything about my initial question.*

Comment: That's interesting. If my app is distributed in binaries and only the end user downloads the contents, it's allowed provided the user accepted the TOS. My software isn't storing anything to distribute it to anyone but the end user that's currently using the software. That seems legit, but I may have missed something. Thanks for your input!